# Tailwindcss does not output majority of classes

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to make a static one page website using tailwind. I am using vscode on microsoft windows. I have followed exactly the installation instructions on https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation and structured my two directories as /scr and /dist as shown.

The output css file is created successfully with no errors, but does not have any of the classes that tailwind advertises. It is 424 lines only and includes css that sets defaults only it seems. Does anyone know how to get tailwind to actually output the css classes that are shown on their website?

my input.css file is:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: After some testing, it looks like {@tailwind base;} is working, but {@tailwind components;} and {@tailwind utilities;} are not. Why would that be?

Comment: Could you please share your `tailwind.config` file content?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I wasn't correctly referencing my index.html file in the tailwind.config.js file. Once I added `content: ["./dist/*.{html,js}"]` the problem was fixed.